# Edit Mysql Table With A Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, edit

I want to edit mysql data using a contact form. When the user clicks edit on the specific post they want to change, it takes them to a form that has the post values in the input fields, and they can change whatever they want about the post. I already have this part working but now I need the change to actually take effect once the user clicks submit. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the PHP that displays all the text from the blog post in mysql into the input fields when the user clicks edit.

```
<?php
        include "../php/db_connect.php";

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

            $id = $_GET['id'];

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $content = $row['content'];
                $written_by = $row['written_by'];
                $category = $row['category'];
            }

        ?>

    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <h1 class="content_heading">Edit A Blog Post</h1>
        <form method="post" action="php/edit_article_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_article_form">
            <span>Title</span>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="input" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/>
            <span>Article</span>
            <textarea rows="20" name="ckeditor1" class="input" style="resize:none;"><?php echo $content ?></textarea>
            <span>Author</span>
            <input type="text" name="written_by" class="input short_input"  value="<?php echo $written_by; ?>"/>
            <span>Category - <i>Spell it right nigga</i></li></span>
            <input type="text" name="category" class="input short_input"  value="<?php echo $category?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="update" class="input submit_button"/>
        </form>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

Now all I need is for the change to take effect when the user clicks submit.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` attribute `method` has a value of `post` which is not the same method you used inside the `isset()` function

You should use:

```
$_GET['id'] //if your method="get"
```

and

```
$_POST['id'] //if your method="post"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the change to appear directly you should re-fresh the page after editing the values

```
header('Location: www.samepage.php');
```